# How to set matButton active (focused) Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

When first and following time user enters the page, placed button is not focused and highlighted by gray color. I tried to set autofocus:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" autofocus>{{'recovery' | translate}}</button>
```

I consider that it is imperfection of Material buttons.

How to set focused material button in last Angular?

Comment: none of the solutions below worked for me for buttons on a dialog, but this answer works, namely to add `cdkTrapFocus [cdkTrapFocusAutoCapture]="true"` to a div containing the button to be focused, and then adding `cdkFocusInitial` to the button. also import A11yModule  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63774899/458370

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just set focus to the button at component's life-cycle hook **ngAfterViewInit** for example:

### Template

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" #btnRef="matButton">{{'recovery' | translate}}</button>
```

### Ts file

```
...
@ViewChild('btnRef') buttonRef: MatButton;
...
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.buttonRef.focus();
}
...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This did not work for me when trying to focus on a button inside an opened matDialogModal.

Answer (score 8):

```
<button mat-button #btnFocus=matButton [autofocus]="btnFocus.focus()">Post</button>
```

Answer (score 8):

It looks like angular material already has directive for that. Check [Angular A11y](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview)

```
<button mat-button cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63774899/1461862

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `focus` method of [MatButton](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview).

```html
<button mat-raised-button #button>{{ 'recovery' | translate }}</button>
```

```js
@ViewChild('button') button;

ngOnInit() {
  this.button.focus()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" #btn [autofocus]="btn.focus()">{{'recovery' | translate}}</button>
```

Comment: please elaborate a little more what the question owner did wrong

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.