# cdkFocusInitial attribute not focusing the DOM element

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular10

In Angular 10 project, I have a form with 2 inputs named Username and Password. I am using
`cdkFocusInitial` attribute on username field, however it's not focusing on page load. Here is a StackBlitz example that shows the issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4amzj4?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffocus-monitor-directives-example.html

```
<div class="example-focus-monitor">

    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
        <input cdkFocusInitial  aria-label="Username" class="username"
             matInput
            placeholder="Enter Username" type="text">
  </mat-form-field>

        <br/>
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
    <input   aria-label=" Password" class="password"  matInput placeholder="Enter Password"
            type="text">
        </mat-form-field>
</div>


  


  [1]: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4amzj4?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffocus-monitor-directives-example.html
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add in first div:

```
cdkTrapFocus [cdkTrapFocusAutoCapture]="true"
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4amzj4-nz2yh4?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffocus-monitor-directives-example.html

Comment: Adding `A11yModule` to module imports is required

Comment: Why not having the code here, instead of (in addition to) Stackblitz. There are not too many lines of code

Answer (score 9):

This is because cdkFocusInitial is used in the context of FocusTrap. You can read about it [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview).

For performing autofocus, you can create a directive, which will take the element's reference and focus it.

```
import { AfterContentInit, Directive, ElementRef, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[autoFocus]"
})

export class AutofocusDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  @Input() public appAutoFocus: boolean;

  public constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  public ngAfterContentInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.el.nativeElement.focus();
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

Use this directive like

```
<input
    autoFocus
    aria-label="Username"
    class="username"
    matInput
    placeholder="Enter Username"
    type="text"
>
```

If you use this multiple times on a page, the one where it used last will be focused.
Cheers!

Comment: I couldn't get anything else to work, but this worked brilliantly. thanks

Comment: It works - but I need to remove `@Input() appAutoFocus` - which doesn't do anything in the Directive. Any reason why its there?